# Route model binding not working on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have been trying to solve this issue since two days but no luck. I do have a update method on my ArticleController that is responsible to update the articles on my database:

```
public function update(Article $articles,  ArticleRequest $request){

    $article = Article::findOrFail($articles);

    $article->update($request->all());

    return redirect('articles');
    }
```

Here is my blade file to show those results:

```
@extends('app')




@section ('content')
<div class="container">

<h1>Edit:  {{$article->title}}</h1>



{!!Form::model($article,['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=>['ArticleController@update', $article->id] ])!!}
 @include('pages.partials', ['submitButtonText' => 'Edit Article'])


{!!Form::close()!!}
@include('errors.error')

</div>


@endsection
```

I get error Article var doesnt exists.

Comment: can you remove     $article = Article::findOrFail($articles);

Answer (score 1):

When you set up route-model binding, behind the scenes Laravel retrieves the appropriate model instance for you and passes it into your controller method. In your example, the `Article $articles` argument represents an instance of the Article model - not just the id. Therefore, the following line is both unnecessary (since you already have the appropriate model instance), and incorrect (since `findOrFail` expects an integer to be passed to it - not a model instance):

```
$article = Article::findOrFail($articles);
```

I would change your controller method to be:

```
public function update(Article $articles,  ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $articles->update($request->all());

    return redirect('articles');
}
```

If you still have trouble with that, "die and dump" your `$articles` variable to ensure you have route-model binding set up correctly.